# Dplyr Grouped Mutate Do alternative?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a series of accounts with unique account numbers that can be grouped by a sequence number. I would like to use the unique account number at the beginning of each sequence as a new reference column for the entire group. I can accomplish my task with `Do` however I think my solution is pretty inelegant. Using this example code, could someone demonstrate a cleaner way to achieve the output?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Seq = factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)),
         Num = c("8432", "a2233", "234", 
                 "b532", "q265", "z4453", "1232", 
                 "a644", "124"))

df %>% 
   group_by(Seq) %>%
   do(mutate(.,HH = as_vector(.[1,2]))) %>%
   ungroup()
```

Output:

```
    # A tibble: 9 × 3
     Seq   Num    HH
  <fctr> <chr> <chr>
1      1  8432  8432
2      1 a2233  8432
3      1   234  8432
4      2  b532  b532
5      2  q265  b532
6      2 z4453  b532
7      2  1232  b532
8      3  a644  a644
9      3   124  a644
```

Comment: Your code is giving error.  Which version of `dplyr` you have?

Comment: 0.5.0  Apologies for that... I will update my RStudio version and correct.

Comment: If you can update with the solution you got, it will be great

Comment: Perhaps `library(stringi); df %>% group_by(Seq)  %>% mutate(HH = Num[stri_detect(Num, regex="[a-z]")])`

Comment: I updated Rstudio and am running Tidyverse 1.1.0 and did not get an error, I am not sure why it wouldnt be running for you. I was able to copy the above code and run it without issues. The strings I am working with are not uniquely identified by the presence of an alpha-numeric... I structured it like that in the example for visual reference.

Comment: Could you edit your post with the expected output so that it becomes more clear (as I am not able to run your code).  Also, some description about the logic you are applying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `stri_match` from `stringi` and create the 'HH' column

```
library(stringi)
df %>%
   group_by(Seq) %>% 
   mutate(HH = Num[which(stri_detect(Num, regex="[a-z]"))[1]])
#     Seq   Num    HH
#  <fctr> <chr> <chr>
#1      1  a432  a432
#2      1 a2233  a432
#3      1   234  a432
#4      2  b532  b532
#5      2  q265  b532
#6      2 z4453  b532
#7      2  1232  b532
#8      3  a644  a644
#9      3   124  a644
```

---

Or using `grep`

```
df %>%
   group_by(Seq) %>% 
   mutate(HH = Num[grep("^[0-9]+$", Num, invert=TRUE)[1]])
```

#### Update

Based on the new updated data, it seems like we wanted to get the first element of 'Num'

```
df %>%
  group_by(Seq) %>%
  mutate(HH = first(Num))
#   Seq   Num    HH
#  <fctr> <chr> <chr>
#1      1  8432  8432
#2      1 a2233  8432
#3      1   234  8432
#4      2  b532  b532
#5      2  q265  b532
#6      2 z4453  b532
#7      2  1232  b532
#8      3  a644  a644
#9      3   124  a644
```

Comment: Unfortunately that code does not work if the leading character is a number. I updated the sample code to include a non-alpha character as the lead character. Thank you!

Comment: @Farmer updated the post again.  I hope you don't have any new rules

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help. My apologies for the sample code leading to a spurious pattern assumption. This works perfectly.